# How to find all solutions of the ODE $x'=3x^{\frac{2}{3}}, x(0)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

Problem: Find **all** the solutions of the IVP $$x'=3x^{\frac{2}{3}}, x(0)=0$$ for $t\geq 0$.

Here $3x^{\frac{2}{3}}$ is not $C^1$, so the existence and uniqueness theorem does not apply here.

My guess the solutions is $$x=\left\{\begin{matrix}
0 & \text{if }0\leq t< t_{0} \\ 
 (t-t_{0})^3 &  \text{ if }t\geq t_{0}  
\end{matrix}\right.$$
$t_{0}\in\mathbb{R^+}$ or $t_{0}\rightarrow+\infty$.

But my professor told me that there are a lot more!

My main question is: **How can I find all the solutions, and then prove that they are all the solutions, rigorously?**

Comment: @mfl I know. I want all the solutions. When $t_{0}=+\infty$, $x=0$ is the solution in my expression.

Comment: @EricSun $+\infty\notin\Bbb R^+$

Comment: @Holo In some general sense, and it is not the point. Trivial solution does no help to my question.

Comment: @Vasya Yes it can be, and my expression exactly means that, but my question is: are these all the solutions and how to *prove* it?

Comment: @EricSun I understand but it is important to understand, I also won't write "and $t_0\to\infty$" as a limit is not a number, the way I would write it is "$t_0\in\Bbb R^+\cup\{+\infty\}$"(Or just "and the trivial solution $x\equiv0$), I understand that this is not the main point of the question but it is better to understand and fix this kind of things before an exam IMO. Regard to the question, "My professor told me that it is fine to define the rational power of negative numbers", but your solution is undefined on negative numbers.

Comment: @Holo Updated. Also I'm sure people won't have so many difficulties to understand my question.

Comment: my intentions weren't to imply the question is unclear. Regards to the actual question, can I assume you proved the uniqueness of antiderivative(up to a constant)?

Comment: @Holo Of course you can use that. You can use whatever you want if you have an answer to the question.

Comment: Do you know what your professor means by $x^{2/3}$ when $x<0$?

Comment: As far as I can tell those are all solutions on $[0,\infty)$. There is a maximal solution $x(t)=t^3$ and a minimal solution $x(t)=0$. All the other solutions are between these two. (I am considering $x^{2/3}=(x^2)^{1/3}\ge0$).

Comment: @Did It means taking cubic root and then square it.

Comment: Then $x^{2/3}\geqslant0$ for every real number $x$, and which other solutions your professor can allude to, is escaping me. Sure you did not misunderstand?

Comment: @Did I asked him about $-t^3$ he said it’s not a solution and there are a lot more.

Comment: Wit these conventions about two-thirds powers, a proof that there is no other solution is not that difficult, actually... First show that $x(t)\geqslant0$ for every $t\geqslant0$ and every solution. Next, assume that $x(t_1)=x_1$ with $x_1>0$ for some $t_1>0$, and apply Cauchy-Lipschitz to deduce the value of $x(t)$ for every $t$ in some interval $[t_2,+\infty)$ depending on $(t_1,x_1)$, with $x(t_2)=0$. Finally show that $x(t)=0$ for every $t$ in $[0,t_2]$. End of the proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, we can build $x'$, so $x$ is continuous. Since $x^{2/3}=(x^{1/3})^2$, we have $x'\ge 0$, so $x$ is increasing. Then $x$ is either constant, zero, on $J:=[0,\infty)$, or there exist a maximal $t_0=\sup x^{-1}(\ \{0\}\ )=\max x^{-1}(\ \{0\}\ )$ in $J$ so that $x(t_0)=0$. We will only consider this last case, $t_0<\infty$.

Then we have $x'>0$ on $(t_0,\infty)$. Now we forget about the condition in $0$ for a while, solve the given differential equation in $(t_0,\infty)$, knowing $x>0$. On $(0,\infty)$, the function $t\to t^{1/3}$ is of class $C^1$, so we can build as compositum the differentiable function 
$$
y = x^{1/3}\ ,
$$
which satisfies by the chain rule
$$
y'=
(x^{1/3})'
=\frac 13x^{-2/3}\cdot x'
=\frac 13x^{-2/3}\cdot 3 x^{2/3}=1\ .
$$
From $y'=1$ on $(t_0,\infty)$ we find a constant $C$ with $y(t)=t+C$ on $(t_0,\infty)$. So far we know about $x$ that it is $0$ on $[0,t_0]$, it is $t\to y^3(t)=(t+C)^3$, and it is continuous in $t_0$. The only matching constant is $C=-t_0$. We get the solutions and only the solutions from the OP. (It is clear that these are of class $C^1$ and satisfy the given differential equation.)