# Picard–Lindelöf theorem - ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Consider the following example:

[image]

This initial value problem as infinitely many solutions, because the Picard–Lindelöf theorem is not met. Indeed, $f'_x(t,x)$ is not defined for $x(0)=0$. What I have no idea is:  Why $\phi_c(t)=0$ for $t \in (-\infty,c]$. Where $\phi_c(t)=(t-c)^3$ comes from?

Comment: I see, for $x(t)=0$, I have $\frac{dx}{dt}=0$, and plugging $x(t)=0$ in my differential equation, it works.  Why $\phi_c(t)=0$ for $t \in (-\infty,c]$. Where $\phi_c(t)=(t-c)^3$ comes from?

Comment: Note that $x(t)$ need not be zero for $t<0$: for example, $x(t)=t^3$ is also a solution. Another solution is $x(t)=t^3$ for $t<0$ and $x(t)=0$ for $t\ge0$.

Comment: @JohnM.: My apologies, I was working too fast and made a mistake - see: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2862598/how-to-find-all-solutions-of-the-ode-x-3x-frac23-x0-0 for the part of the problem I did not explain properly.

Comment: I'm  sure this answer is good, but some steps are not clear. If you can spell down all the steps in easier way, I'd appreciate that.